# allignment of images in table view cell is not proper

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have created table view with images but that images are not in proper line .i want all images to be in a same line
help me in this to display all images in simulator since  i have more than 7 cases under switch.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];



    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
  UIImageView *imageView=[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"wake up";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"wake up at 6 am and get ready for office";
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"wake-up-early-200.jpg"];
           break;
           case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"remainders";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"today is ajay's bday wish him ";
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"remainders.jpg"];
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"shopping";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"buy vegetables,fruits,dresses";
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"shopping.jpg"];
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.textLabel.text=@"meeting";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"meeeting at lanuch pad by 4pm";
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"meeting.jpg"];
            break;
          case 4:
            cell.textLabel.text=@"airport";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"bala is coming receive him on time";
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"airport.jpg"];
            break;
        case 5:
            cell.textLabel.text=@"games";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"time for refresh";
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"games.jpg"];
            break;
        case 6:
            cell.textLabel.text=@"lunch";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"go to lunch by 1pm";
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"lunch.jpg"];
            break;
        case 7:
            cell.textLabel.text=@"coffee";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"go to ccd at 3pm";
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"coffee.jpg"];
        case 8:
            cell.textLabel.text=@"super market";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"buy household items";
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"market.jpg"];
            break;
        case 12:
            cell.textLabel.text=@"iPhone app";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"iPhone app development training";
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone.jpg"];
            break;
    case 11:
            cell.textLabel.text=@"home";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"going to home by 11pm";
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.jpg"];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }




    //cell.textLabel.text = [todoitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"This Is A Very Very Long String";

        return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please properly format your question (use control+K to fix indentation problems, currently this is very difficult to read)

Comment: Are the images the same size? No transparent frame?

Comment: i got it..i have many case but only 5 case are taken and displayed in simulator ..why so it happens??

Comment: Please explain your needs better so I can help you

Comment: Can you add image of output so we can understand.?

Comment: So share all your Table view related code :)

Comment: Show the code for `numberOfRowsInSection`. This determines how many rows are displayed.

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //return [todoitems count];
    if ([todoitems count] != 0) {
        return [todoitems count];
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}

Comment: is it wright?are i have to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cell.imageView is default size of UITableViewCell. I would recommend you go to interface builder and drag a UIImageView in UITableViewCell and define its size and give the UIImageView tag value equal to 1.

```
Here in cell for Index path delegate access UIImageView this way

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
UIImageView *imageView=[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"wake up";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"wake up at 6 am and get ready for office";

        imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"wake-up-early-200.jpg"];
           break;
           case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"remainders";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"today is ajay's bday wish him ";

        imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"remainder.jpg"];
            break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: i have given return todoitems count

Comment: Make sure - (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{ return 12;} it sud return 12 rows check your array size print in NSLog and check its size

Answer (score 1):

`todoitems=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:    @"1.wake up",@"2.remainders",@"3.shopping",@"4.meeting",@"5.airport",@"6.home",nil];`

should change to:

`todoitems=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:    @"1.wake up",@"2.remainders",@"3.shopping",@"4.meeting",@"5.airport",@"6.home",@"games",@"lunch",@"coffee",@"super market",@"iPhone app",@"home",nil];`

I have to include all items which i have used in switch case..
that is the mistake i have done

Comment: Its count is 6 and your cases are 12. Fix ur array